# Eigenvalue with smallest real part of a complex $N \times N$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-process

Is there any technique (trick) to find the eigenvalue with smallest real part of any general complex matrix $[a_{ij}]_{N \times N}$. Without finding all the eigenvalues explicitly and then identifying.

$\textbf{Context :}$ This problem is relevant for finding for example the statistics of number of specific $i \rightarrow j$ jumps taken by a markov process in the long time limit.

Comment: For a general matrix there is little that can be done. The eigenvalue with the smallest real part can either have the smallest or the largest modulus of all the matrices eigenvalues. This limits what can be done with subspace methods. If the matrices that you are really interested in have some nice/odd properties, then they will almost certainly be needed.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thank you. I am actually dealing with rate matrices of small dimensions $~5$. At least for $~4$ cases things are manegable but messy. So I thought if any techniques are available to find lowest (real part) eigenvalue, which is the only thing I need for the specific problem at hand.

Comment: I am afraid that I do not recognize the term 'rate' matrix. I suspect that it is well known with the field of probability theory. Do rate matrices have any special properties, such as being symmetric, positive definite, nonnegative, etc., i.e., properties that might help from a purely computational point of view? Also, I recommend that you add a few word about why such small matrices represent a problem. Do you have a great many of them? Do you need an extremely accurate result? Why can you not afford to find all 5 eigenvalues?